# Predict placement of an object in 3D space

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision

I am trying to find a way to train a model to predict the correct placement of entities like a tree, dog and cat in a natural 3D environment. Any help regarding how I could use textual data to learn correct placement of objects in 3D space would be a great help. I am a little lost on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Find some university professor and make your PhD on that topic. You might use as a starting point [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/). You are likely to fail, even in four years of full-time work. You certainly would be able to public interesting peer-reviewed papers.

Comment: xd, i think its time to do a PhD then.

Comment: Finding a good advisor is an important first step